# How to change multiple columns' types in pyspark?

Tags: python, select, types, casting, pyspark

I am just studying pyspark. I want to change the column types like this:

```
df1=df.select(df.Date.cast('double'),df.Time.cast('double'),
          df.NetValue.cast('double'),df.Units.cast('double'))
```

You can see that df is a data frame and I select 4 columns and change all of them to double. Because of using select, all other columns are ignored.

But, if df has hundreds of columns and I just need to change those 4 columns. I need to keep all the columns. So, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for c in df.columns:
    # add condition for the cols to be type cast
    df=df.withColumn(c, df[c].cast('double'))
```

Comment: @ags29 Works on small datasets, I have 2K columns with around 200K records. Wanted to convert everything to integer except 3 columns. Taking forever! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df.select([col(column).cast('double') for column in df.columns])
```

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't let you update the df in place like the answer above

Comment: Not sure you are correct to be honest, AFAIK Spark dataframes are immutable and therefore cannot be updated inplace. And even if you could, I don't see how the solution above could be updating anything inplace. If you have a reference to back up your statement I would be interested to read.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase. I don’t mean in place like in pandas where you can set the in place parameter. I mean it’s not letting me update the df in one line. One line is always more professional, especially if compared with a for loop.

Comment: Don't understand at all. My solution is 1 line, the accepted answer runs a statement for each col requiring casting i.e.the direct opposite of what you are saying

Comment: It’s one line but it doesn’t return the original dataset with the updated columns. Only returns the updated column. That’s why it wasn’t the accepted solution.

Comment: Actually it does return all columns of the dataset (updated). What it doesn't do is allow for differential treatment of a subset of columns, which is what the accepted answer did (and presumably what the OP wanted). So again, your statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way using `selectExpr()`:**

```
df1 = df.selectExpr("cast(Date as double) Date", 
    "cast(NetValueas string) NetValue")
df1.printSchema()
```

**Using `withColumn()`:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, StringType

df1 = df.withColumn("Date", df["Date"].cast(DoubleType())) \
      .withColumn("NetValueas ", df["NetValueas"].cast(StringType()))
df1.printSchema()
```

Check [types](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like to have a non-for-loop answer that preserves the original set of columns whilst only updating a subset. The following should be the answer you were looking for:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df.select(*(col(c).cast("double").alias(c) for c in subset),*[x for x in df.columns if x not in subset])
```

where `subset` is a list of the columnnames you would like to update.